# CollapsingToolbarLayout not collapsing properly

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` which has scroll flags of `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"`.

It is supposed to start collapsing as soon as user scrolls down & it does it perfectly. But there is one problem: It must show up when the user scrolls to the top of the page.

If the user keeps moving her finger on the screen while scrolling, It works as expected & the collapsed stuff show up, but if user's finger leaves the screen and the app keeps scrolling without user's finger on the screen, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` won't show up even though user has scrolled up as much as possible.

Xml layout of the activity looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/home_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="rtl">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"


            >

            <include layout="@layout/plain_toolbar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollable_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HI"
                android:textSize="200dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <!--</FrameLayout>-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_nav"
    android:name="ir.flashcards.english.view.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"></fragment>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I move my finger on the screen in order for the scrolling to begin and let it scroll till it reaches the top of the layout, the navbar looks like:
[image]

And I should pull it manually in order for the toolbar to expand also if I had not let my fingers leave the screen and had scrolled little by little the toolbar would have expanded like: 
[image]

Comment: Could you add screenshot of misbehavior and xml code of your layout?

Comment: @SergeyShustikov Thanks for your comment, I added those.